# Not getting Push notifications on channel created with ADMIN SDK Users.Watch

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to setup a push webhook notification channel using Users.Watch() method from Admin SDK.
Example code:

```
var channel = NewChannel();
var req = service.Users.Watch(channel);
req.Domain = domain;
req.Event = eventEnum;
var res = req.Execute();
```

The properties of channel object look like below:

```
{
    "address": "https://mynotifcationUrl/Notify/EAAAAMKLu07pdnHc96K6qJxgFgGZPREK6SJqD9llJaIcUfXE",
    "expiration": null,
    "id": "7ebe654b-2b90-4bde-b54d-1d1173ecaebb",
    "kind": null,
    "params": null,
    "payload": null,
    "resourceId": null,
    "resourceUri": null,
    "token": null,
    "type": "web_hook",
    "ETag": null
}
```

The response I get looks like below:

```
{
    "address": null,
    "expiration": 1696158609000,
    "id": "7ebe654b-2b90-4bde-b54d-1d1173ecaebb",
    "kind": "api#channel",
    "params": null,
    "payload": null,
    "resourceId": "jQ8-pruwTPaXQvkq_xCDK6V3tpM",
    "resourceUri": "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json&domain=mydomain.net&event=update",
    "token": null,
    "type": null,
    "ETag": "\"rQ3qpTrpjMqlOD9Fi6ZCgnpo6zAdUtM4Y4wU0J6c8Yw/I-irlN9nkQrcLJ046bZDCL02x30\""
}
```

However, I never get a sync response on the endpoint. Also, even after updates to users info like name etc. I don't get a request on my url.
The url I am using uses a signed certificate from and the subject also matches the dns name in the url.
Can someone please help me with why am I not getting the post request on my endpoint?